# Why can't I see the title of the input validation form in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't see the title of the validation form in HTML5. My code is:

```html
<form id="form_1" class="row g-3" value=1 selected="selected" method="GET" onsubmit="check_input_users()" action="Paginautenteloggato.html">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" minlength="4" maxlength="10" title="Scegli una password di non più di 8 caratteri tra numeri e lettere" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I miss the password form why I can't see the title (Scegli una password di non più di 8 caratteri tra numeri e lettere)? Should I create another function that checks the form?

Comment: Are you using a javascript library for displaying the `title` attribute?

Comment: Title is only for when you’re hovering over the input.

Comment: The `title` attribute text becomes visible when you place the mouse cursor on the input field.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute text only becomes visible when you move the mouse cursor over the `input` field.

If you want to make that text permanently visible, you could put it into a `::after` pseudo element as shown in my snippet below:

```css
label[for=inputPassword4] {
position: relative;
}
label[for=inputPassword4]::after {
  content: "Scegli una password di non più di 8 caratteri tra numeri e lettere";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.8em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 160px;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<form id="form_1" class="row g-3" value=1 selected="selected" method="GET" onsubmit="check_input_users()" action="Paginautenteloggato.html">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" name="inputPassword4"
    pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" minlength="4" maxlength="10"
    title="Scegli una password di non più di 8 caratteri tra numeri e lettere" required >
  </div>
</form>
```